# The Dirichlet character modulo a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, dirichlet-character

If I consider all Dirichlet characters modulo a prime number, let's say 5.
Then I can have a form that looks like this:

- [image]

I found that

1. $$\begin{align*}
   \chi_{5,4}^2&= \chi_{5,1} \\ \chi_{5,3}^4&= \chi_{5,1} \\ &\vdots 
   \end{align*}$$ That is, it seems that if I raise a character to some powers, I can get another one.
2. Also, the sum of each row is zero except for $\chi_{5,1}$, and the sum of each column is also zero except for $\chi_{5,4}$

Is this true for all Dirichlet characters modulo a prime number?
If this is true, how should I prove these 2 facts? Thanks.

I'm a very beginner at number theory. If possible, please avoid using group theory and things relating to abstract algebra since I have no idea about what are they. Thank you very much!

Comment: For the sum of a row being $0$: for all $h \in G$, $\sum_{g\in G} \chi(g)=\sum_{g\in G} \chi(hg)=\chi(h)\sum_{g\in G} \chi(g)$. This implies that either $\chi(h)=1$ for all $h$ or $\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)=0$.

Comment: Yes, what you found for $5$ works for all primes.